# ¿Existe una sentencia donde una macro deje hacer el calculate completo antes de brincarse a la siguiente sentencia?

Tags: vba

Hola tengo una macro donde tengo que hacer simulaciones con la función aleatorio, la función aleatorio esta en una matrix de 75000x12, tengo entendido que excel se satura con un cierto número de registros y no recalcula completo toda la hoja y se brinca a la siguiente sentencia, existe alguna sentencia donde la macro deje que se calcule toda la hoja y después se brinque a la siguiente sentencia.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba el comando `DoEvents` justo después de tu parte del código donde haces el cálculo.

[Información DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function):

> ### Función DoEvents
>
> Cede la ejecución para que el sistema operativo pueda procesar otros eventos. La función DoEvents devuelve un entero que representa el número de formularios abiertos en versiones independientes de Visual Basic, como Visual Basic, Professional Edition. DoEvents devuelve cero en todas las demás aplicaciones. DoEvents pasa el control al sistema operativo. Control se devuelve después de que el sistema operativo ha terminado de procesar los eventos de su cola y se hayan enviado todas las claves de la cola de SendKeys . DoEvents resulta más útil para procesos sencillos como permitir a un usuario para la cancelación de un proceso cuando ya ha empezado, por ejemplo la búsqueda de un archivo. Para procesos de larga duración, que revela el procesador se consigue mejor mediante un temporizador o delegar la tarea a un componente de ActiveX EXE.